# htaccess not working after transfer to new server

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I transferred my wordpress sites to a new VPS from shared hosting. I do not know what version of apache was on the last host, but I do know I am on Apache/2.2.15 now. I also set up mass virtual hosting.

Now, I use wordpess permalinks (which generates an htaccess file) to send requests for a directory/file to the index.php file. I also set up a generic site to use this htaccess rewrite:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

This works on the old server. But not the new one. mod_rewrite is enabled, I did verify that.

Comment: Probably better suited for server fault than SO if it works on another server.

Comment: They weren't any help. I'm scraping everywhere now for help lol.

Answer (score 1):

Ah! Figured it out. Fairly simple, I just overlooked it.

I set up the mass virtual with:

```
VirtualDocumentRoot /var/www/html/%0
```

But didn't allow override for the parent directory.

```
<Directory "/var/www/html">
        AllowOverride ALL
</Directory>
VirtualDocumentRoot /var/www/html/%0
```